# if statement giving opposite result on ajax success

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Good day every one, i was working with ajax to check if the values are same or not, i am getting true data on ajax success but when i am using if statement for js alert its giving me opposite result, please assist- here is my code--

index.php

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js">

</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {

setInterval("alert()", 5000);

});
function alert() {

      var aval=1;
      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "php.php",
        data: 'uid=' + aval,
        success: function(html)
            { // this happen after we get result

                 if (html.success == true)
                 { 
                    alert ('Same Value');
                 }
                 else {
                    alert('Different Value')
                 }

             }
        });
}


</script>
Old Value:1<br>
<div>New Value:</div><div id="new" ></div>
```

php.php

```
<?php 
//some php coding which shows result

echo '1';

?>
```

Comment: I agree also you should accept answer

Answer (score 1):

Change your success part to this:

```
success: function (html) {
        if (html == '1') { 
            alert('Same Value');
        } else {
            alert('Different Value');
        }
    }
```

This will check against the value (1 in this case)